# What, exactly, does 'pkg-config --exists' do?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, pkg-config

I recently tried installing an app from source (dwb on Debian Wheezy if it makes a difference). While installing, it would choke on some dependency problem, but to me it seemed I was meeting that dependency. [I wasn't the only person with this problem.](https://bitbucket.org/portix/dwb/issue/450/dwb-compile-error-libsoup-debian-wheezy) Which got me poking around in the project's config.mk.

In config.mk I found several blocks that looked like this:

```
REQPKG=foo
ifeq ($(shell pkg-config --exists $(REQPKG) && echo 1),1)
LIBS=$(REQPKG)
else
$(error Cannot find $(REQPKG))
endif
```

Which seems very counter intuitive to me. I searched and searched. Read the man page, consulted google. Read everything I could about pkg-config and found nothing. The man page is particularly frustrating as it simply lists '--exists' as a flag and gives no description (I guess it's as self explanatory as --help).

I began thinking that Debian's pkg-config had a bug where it returned inverse results. But, as it turns out 'pkg-config --exists' is supposed to return 0 (i.e. False) when the requested package *is present*.

Why is this? Wouldn't it produce cleaner code to return True/False or 1/0 indicating the presence of the required package? You could do this:

```
if (shell pkg-config --exists foo)
/*do things*/
else
/*throw error*/
endif
```

Instead of what looks to me like:

```
ifeq (($(not(True) && True)),True)
/*do things*/
else [...]
```

What am I missing about pkg-config? Does it act this way because it's a shell utility and some strange convention regarding them?

Also, why is the documentation so sparse? Am I missing a resource that would give the info I was looking for?

PS I don't have any real experience with C, so if my example code looks weird...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pkg-config --exists` doesn't create any output it simply returns with an exit code of `0` for success and `1` for failure.

`&&` in the shell runs the right-hand side when the left-hand side returns success.

So that line is running `pkg-config --exists` and iff it returns true (return code of `0`) it then `echo`s a `1` as output. That `1` is then compared against the `1` in the `ifeq`.

And as to why you can't do something simpler here the answer is because make (when not in target rules) doesn't deal with program return codes. Specifically `$(shell)` pays the return code of the shell command being run no attention at all.

Personally, I'd probably have written that test as either:

```
ifeq ($(shell pkg-config --exists $(REQPKG); echo $?),0)
```

or something like

```
REQPKG=foo
REQPKG:=$(shell pkg-config --exists $(REQPKG) && echo '$(REQPKG)')
ifneq ($(REQPKG),)
    LIBS=$(REQPKG)
else
    $(error ...)
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of UNIX commands and library functions return 0 on success.  It's the "sensible default" in that world.

That's why, for example,. the prototypical "Hello, world!" in C ends with "return 0;" and not "return 1" - nonzero codes are considered erroneous.  (Not that anyone is probably going to look at the return value of your HW, but still...)

Answer (score 1):

This seems cleaner to me:

```
pkg-config --exists gtk+-3.0 && echo "Installed" || echo "Not installed"
```

Answer (score 0):

Etan provides very good insight.  But, there is one clarification regarding his recommendation:

```
ifeq ($(shell pkg-config --exists $(REQPKG); echo $?),0)
```

In my case, the return code is not retrievable with `echo $?`, so the comparison always fails.  The line works directly in a terminal, but not within the shell function.  I had to resort to the confusing `&& echo 0`

Anyway, I learned a lot from his description, and thank him for that.